# bc30456 errors... xxxx not a member of yyyy

Tags: vb.net, member

Hi I have just started to learn VB as it is in VS 2015. I am doing exercises from the book Beginning Visual Basic 2015 by Bryon Newsome. I can't get any help from the publishers forum or the publisher themselves. I managed to fix this type of error in an earlier exercise, but can't see anything with the below to fix.

Here is the code from pages 214 to 215:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btn2Buttons_Click(sender As Object,
    e As EventArgs) Handles btn2Buttons.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Your Internet connection will now be closed.",
           "Network Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
           MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) _
   = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            lblResults.Text = "OK Clicked"
            'Call some method here
        Else
            lblResults.Text = "Cancel Clicked"
            'Call some method here
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

The following is from the two error messages:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   BC30456 'OKCancel' is not a member of 'MessageBoxButtons'.  MessageBoxButtons   E:\Document\Programing\VB\MessageBoxButtons\MessageBoxButtons\Form1.vb  5

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   BC30456 'Forms' is not a member of 'Windows'.   MessageBoxButtons   E:\Document\Programing\VB\MessageBoxButtons\MessageBoxButtons\Form1.vb  7
```

There is one label: lblResults with text property Nothing clicked

There is one button: btn2buttons with text property 2 Buttons.

Comment: Because you the same project name as MessageBoxButtons, vb thinks this is a member of your project. Add the fully qualified name where these constants belong to: System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel

Comment: Hi... where would I put that line you suggested  in the above code? VB complained at the places I put it. I am right at the beginning with VB! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
If MessageBox.Show("Your Internet connection will now be closed.",
       "Network Notification", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
       System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Information, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            lblResults.Text = "OK Clicked"
            'Call some method here
        Else
            lblResults.Text = "Cancel Clicked"
            'Call some method here
        End If
```